# How to use android checkbox sharedpreference to play music

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sharedpreferences

I am fairly new to the concept of shared preferences in android, but for a project I have to implement it. I have gotten somewhat of an idea from these links of what I am trying to do...but still kind of lost

[How to implement shared preferences](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2223089)

[Android Media and checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17689408/android-media-player-wont-work-with-checkbox)

Basically I am trying to set up a very simple settings preference menu in the main activity that when you tap on the settings icon/the three dots symbol in android, you will be presented with the preference menu which has the option of tapping a checkbox to turn music on or off. When the checkbox is tapped(selected), music will play, when the checkbox is tapped again(un selected) then music will stop.

I am just a little lost on how to implement this using sharedpreferences. Hoping someone could give a very simple step by step answer or tutorial. Thanks

Comment: Try: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm

Comment: One more for good measure: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html

Comment: @sparkysword Thank you, but I saw these already and they don't show how to do the menu item with preferences.